# Redireccionamiento a Login - Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

Al momento en que una sesión caduca, no puedo redirigir a la ruta del login para que puedan volver a iniciar sesión.

En el siguiente código verán algunas de las opciones que estuve intentado, y requiero que sea dentro de este código la intercepción para redirigirse a la ruta de login.

```
    import jwtDefaultConfig from './jwtDefaultConfig'
    import { initialAbility } from '@/libs/acl/config'
    import useJwt from '@/auth/jwt/useJwt'
    
    export default class JwtService {
      // Will be used by this service for making API calls
      axiosIns = null
    
      // jwtConfig <= Will be used by this service
      jwtConfig = { ...jwtDefaultConfig }
    
      // For Refreshing Token
      isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
    
      // For Refreshing Token
      subscribers = []
    
      constructor(axiosIns, jwtOverrideConfig) {
        this.axiosIns = axiosIns
        this.jwtConfig = { ...this.jwtConfig, ...jwtOverrideConfig }
    
        // Request Interceptor
        this.axiosIns.interceptors.request.use(
          config => {
            // Get token from localStorage
            const accessToken = this.getToken()
    
            // If token is present add it to request's Authorization Header
            if (accessToken) {
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
              config.headers.Authorization = `${this.jwtConfig.tokenType} ${accessToken}`
            }
            return config
          },
          error => Promise.reject(error),
        )
    
        // Add request/response interceptor
        this.axiosIns.interceptors.response.use(
          response => response,
          error => {
            // const { config, response: { status } } = error
            const { config, response } = error
            const originalRequest = config
    
            // if (status === 401) {
            if (response && response.status === 401) {
              // Remove userData from localStorage
              localStorage.removeItem('userData')
    
              localStorage.removeItem(useJwt.jwtConfig.storageTokenKeyName)
              localStorage.removeItem(useJwt.jwtConfig.storageRefreshTokenKeyName)
    
              // Reset ability
              this.$ability.update(initialAbility)
    
              // Redirect to login page
              /* next({ name: 'auth-login' }) */
              /* return { name: 'auth-login' } */
              /* this.$router.push({ name: 'auth-login' }) */
            }
            return Promise.reject(error)
          },
        )
      }
}
```

he intentado validar con el error de unauthenticated y no me he es posible tampoco lograr un redireccionamiento. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como poder lograr un redireccionamiento desde este codigo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]